# Haskell newline, how?

Tags: haskell, dictionary, io, functional-programming, ghc

i have got a problem with the following code. It is supposed to be a kind of dictionary asking first for a german word, than for a bavarian word and saving both in a .txt file. Then newLine for the next pair. Program terminates when you stop entering new words. UPDATE:
The newLine "/n" does not work. How can i solve that?

```
 main :: IO ()
 main = do
  putStrLn "Deutsches Wort: "
  deutsch <-getLine
   if  deutsch  /= []
    then do
    putStrLn "Bayerisches Wort: "
    bayerisch <- getLine
    appendFile "woerterbuch.txt" (deutsch++ " "++ bayerisch++ " /n")
    putStrLn (deutsch ++ " ist auf bayerisch " ++ bayerisch)
    main
  else return()
```

Comment: Servus Mauritius. Your indentation is… mixed. Can you please make sure that the code actually matches the one on your system? Also, `writeFile` _always_ truncates files. Also, `bayerisch/n` shouldn't work.

Comment: changed the indentation. so obviously i misunderstood the writeFile function. How can i change my program to save a pair of 2 words to a .txt File and after that newline?

Comment: You `isNotEmpty` function could be simplified. You are basically doing `if condition then True else False`.

Comment: Did you try `"\n"` instead of `"/n"` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

```
import System.IO
import System.Environment
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = do
  (fileName:_) <- getArgs
  unless (null fileName) $ 
    withFile fileName WriteMode makeDictionary
  where    
    makeDictionary :: Handle -> IO()
    makeDictionary h = do
      putStrLn "Deutsches Wort: "
      deutsch <-getLine
      if not . null $ deutsch
        then do
          hPutStr h $ deutsch++" "
          putStrLn "Bayerisches Wort: "
          bayerisch <- getLine
          hPutStrLn h bayerisch
          putStrLn (deutsch ++ " ist auf bayerisch " ++ bayerisch)
          makeDictionary h
        else return()
```

Your revised version looks like it should work, but the advantages here is that the file is not being repeatedly opened and closed.  Although I'm not sure if GHC is smart enough to keep it open in your case.  Also, its generally better to check for empty strings with null instead of comparing to an empty list.

Edited per chepner's comment.

Comment: thanks for that version! do you also know how i can give the file that it should be saved in as an argument when you run it in shell? I tried with args<- getArgs but it is not working

Comment: Edited to accept a filename.  But beware, this will crash if no argument is passed, but will ignore any arguments past the first.

Comment: I would check if `deutsch` is null before writing it to the file.